# xcode ld: 64-bit LDR/STR not 8-byte aligned

Tags: ios, xcode

when I archive a static lib libtyrtcsdk.a on one mac by xcode , then I copy the lib to another mac, and build a demo with the lib libtyrtcsdk.a, and xcode report this error as below, can anyone give help to this? thanks very much:

`ld: 64-bit LDR/STR not 8-byte aligned: from -[SdkObj getSendFrameRate:] (0x1001BC0E0)` to `l427@0x0000B0EC (0x1004D41D4)` in `'-[SdkObj getSendFrameRate:]'` from `/Volumes/LYG/work/ppSVN/GoodVisialFiles/GoodVisial/GoodVisial/ThirdPart/videoSDK/sdk2.2.0/lib/libtyrtcsdk.a(sdkobj.o)` for architecture arm64

Comment: How are you copying the lib file?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is caused by a LLVM alignment compatibility issue with older Xcode Versions / LLVM compiler.

The solution would be to update your xcode to 6.3.1 or greater.
Have a look [here]: https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/issues/3984

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: In my case, only Release mode has problem. Debug mode has not problem? I do not know why. Every setting is the same ( Architecture...)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem, then i changed NSInteger to int and it worked, i think it's because of 32bit/64bit architecture. Try changing NSInteger to int.

Answer (score 0):

I use Xcode Version 7.3.1 (7D1014), and solve this accidentally by rearrange some lib.a close to bottom in  -> general -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries.

I guess some lib may depend others duration the link phase, that is may be why Cocoa pods frameworks come to the last.